# How to deactivate a function after being activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I can activate a function on a certain click event but I want to stop that function whenever I do a click event on another div.

This is my function so far :

```
$('#text-tab').click(function() {
    writeOnCanvas(true);
});

$('#paint-tab, #sticker-tab, #done-tab').click(function() {
    writeOnCanvas(false);
});


function writeOnCanvas(bool) {
    if(bool) {
        $('body').click(function(e) {

            var clickedOnCanvas = e.target.id == "canvas" || $(e.target).parents('#canvas').length ? true : false;
            var alreadyTextArea = $('textarea.textarea_editable')[0];

            if(clickedOnCanvas) {
                if(alreadyTextArea) {
                    drawSentence();
                } else {
                    createTextArea(e);
                }
            }
        });

        $('#text > div > .color_choice').click(function() {
            var textColor = $(this).css('background-color');
            $('.textarea_editable').css('color', textColor);
        });

        $('#text > div > div:not(".color_choice")').click(function() {
            var textSize = $(this).css('font-size');
            $('.textarea_editable').css('font-size', textSize);
            $('canvas').attr('data-textSize', textSize);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('stop working');
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, when I click on #text-tab, I put my function to "true", this is working perfectly. However, even if I click on #paint-tab, #sticker-tab or even #done-tab, the function is still working even thought I see the console.log('stop working');

EDIT :

I tried to put a global variable but now my function refuse to work even if I click on #text-tab and the global variable is set to true.

```
var WRITEONCANVAS = false;
writeOnCanvas();

$('#text-tab').click(function() {
    WRITEONCANVAS = true;
});

$('#paint-tab, #sticker-tab, #done-tab').click(function() {
    WRITEONCANVAS = false;
});


function writeOnCanvas() {
    if(WRITEONCANVAS) {
        $('body').click(function(e) {

            var clickedOnCanvas = e.target.id == "canvas" || $(e.target).parents('#canvas').length ? true : false;
            var alreadyTextArea = $('textarea.textarea_editable')[0];

            if(clickedOnCanvas) {
                if(alreadyTextArea) {
                    drawSentence();
                } else {
                    createTextArea(e);
                }
            }
        });

        $('#text > div > .color_choice').click(function() {
            var textColor = $(this).css('background-color');
            $('.textarea_editable').css('color', textColor);
        });

        $('#text > div > div:not(".color_choice")').click(function() {
            var textSize = $(this).css('font-size');
            $('.textarea_editable').css('font-size', textSize);
            $('canvas').attr('data-textSize', textSize);
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: because you are binding click events, they are additive, they do not replace each other.... So each time you call the function, it is binding another click event tot the element, it is not removing it.

Comment: You need to set a global variable to false to begin with that is then set to true inside the function instead of setting the function to false.

Comment: You could use http://api.jquery.com/off/ - but @Paul12_ 's suggestion to have a single handler and check within that handler will make the code a lot cleaner.  (you could use a `.data()` value instead of a global/outer-scoped variable)

Comment: Every thing fine for me but may an issue with HTML

Comment: I tried to solution of @Paul12_ but it still doesn't work. Not sure thought I did it right? See my edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unbind` to remove a bound function such as `click`

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jc4wzerf/1/

The key line is:

```
$('.body-text').unbind( "click" )
```

In your case, you would use:

```
$('body').unbind( "click" )
```

**EDIT**

My fault, `unbind` is deprecated in 3.0. As an alternative, you can just use `off` as suggested by *charlietfl*

https://jsfiddle.net/jc4wzerf/3/

```
$('body').off( "click" )
```

***or***

Just use a flag and single handler

https://jsfiddle.net/jc4wzerf/2

Comment: Aaah the famous unbind! Thank you very much, I made this work with my code. Many thanks!

Comment: You bet, it is worth noting that you could use a global flag like the others were mentioning above if you really wanted to.. that would look something like this https://jsfiddle.net/jc4wzerf/2/

Comment: `unbind()` is deprecated

Comment: It has used `off()` internally for years...just use `off()`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @charlietfl, I updated the answer. Didn't realize that it was deprecated in 3.0

Comment: Do note also this will remove all listeners. If you only want a specific one need to add the handler reference